I've disabled public network access, created a vnet, subnet, and private endpoint, now how do I connect back to my Azure resource?
Through the Azure portal I've created an Azure AI Search service with no public access, then connected it to my virtual network and subnet, and created a private endpoint for my search service.
I want to be able to create an index from outside the portal now, but I have no clue what my next steps are. Connection strings and API keys just don't work to connect my code to the resource anymore. Specifically, I'm using a java spring app and terraform mastercard/restapi, but even an answer in general terms without referencing my tools would be highly appreciated.
I've followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/service-create-private-endpoint but I'm not sure what this virtual machine is for and when I test my connection with this guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-rest) I am still not getting a connection.
What should my next steps be?
